# PHP Problems with writing string to text file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, fwrite

I have created form where you can write text.

In PHP it will get the value of this text field and tries to write it to file:

```
$txtFile = $filePath.$counter."_ans.txt";
$f=fopen($txtFile, "wb");
fwrite($f, $word);
fclose($f);
```

When I write text in my language, for example `қазақ`

I launch it. It created .txt file but when I open it, it shows me: `&#1179;аза&#1179;`

Question: What I have to do? My Language is Kazakh.

Comment: Check this [guide](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) by @deceze

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add charset in html

Comment: But you save file in .txt format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your file in UTF-8 you have two solution :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // Server side
```

Or

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> // Client side
```

On the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a BOM (Byte Order Mark) to your file (and open in html format):

```
$txtFile = $filePath.$counter."_ans.txt";
$f=fopen($txtFile, "wb");
$string = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
$string .= $word;
fwrite($f, $string);
fclose($f);
```

But first look what in your variables `var_dump($word)`